# Android findViewById not working in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, layout-inflater, findviewbyid

New and working on ViewPager, and encounter some difficulties that would like you to offer some advice...

### `ViewPagerAdapter class`

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
    private Context _context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) 
    {
        super(fm);  
        _context=context;       
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            f=App_Intro.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        case 1:
            f=LayoutTwo.newInstance(_context);  
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

### ViewPagerStyle1Activity class

```
public class ViewPagerStyle1Activity extends FragmentActivity 
{
    private ViewPager _mViewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter _adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpView();
        setTab();
    }

    private void setUpView()
    {       
         _mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
         _adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
         _mViewPager.setAdapter(_adapter);
         _mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0); 
    }
    private void setTab()
    {
        _mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener()
        {                       
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        findViewById(R.id.first_tab).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        findViewById(R.id.second_tab).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                }
            }                       
        });
    }
}
```

### App_Intro class

```
public class App_Intro extends Fragment 
{
    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) 
    {
        App_Intro f = new App_Intro();          
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_introduce_scroll, null);

          Button calpaidBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calpaidBtn); //RED UNDERLINE ERROR
          calpaidBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
          {
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {  
                   Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                           Uri.parse("https://abc.com"));
                   startActivity(intent);                                      
                   return;  
               }  
           });          
        return root;
    }

}
```

### Question:

It underlines red in the `App_Intro` class for `findViewById` that "`The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type App_Intro`"

How does this be solved? Actually how to put different activities into the ViewPager? Are there any examples?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calpaidBtn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following :

```
 root.findViewById(..)
```